# Batched GPU matrix-matrix multiplication with unevenly sized matrices in Julia using ComponentArrays and CUDA

Tags: deep-learning, parallel-processing, julia

I have two ComponentArrays that each store L compatibly-sized matrices that I want to multiply and store in a third ComponentArray. This is easy to do on the CPU by iterating through the keys with a for loop, but I want to execute everything in parallel on the GPU using CUDA.jl.

Here is an example on the CPU which produces the desired result.

```
using ComponentArrays

a = ComponentArray(L0 = rand(Float32, 2, 2), L1 = rand(Float32, 3, 3))
b = ComponentArray(L0 = rand(Float32, 2, 2), L1 = rand(Float32, 3, 3))
c = ComponentArray(L0 = zeros(Float32, 2, 2), L1 = zeros(Float32, 3, 3))
names = valkeys(a)

for k in names
    @view(c[k]) .= @view(a[k]) * @view(b[k])
end
```

Now, if we move everything to the GPU:

```
using CUDA

ag = cu(a)
bg = cu(b)
cg = cu(c)
```

We can no longer just iterate with a regular for loop as this is extremely slow. This is shown below:

```
for k in names
    @view(cg[k]) .= @view(ag[k]) * @view(bg[k])
end
```

which returns a warning that scalar indexing was used.

The problem is that matrix multiplication of CUDA arrays calls a CUDA kernel, and doing so within a regular CPU for loop is a big no-no. The proper way is to call one CUDA kernel that does all the multiplications and adds at once for each component.

Now, the library NNlib.jl has a function batched_mul! that essentially does this, but it does not work on ComponentArrays of 2D matrices. Instead, it works on 3D tensors. So, I could use it by converting ag and bg to 3D tensors such that indexing on the third dimension is equivalent to indexing the components of ag and bg. However, this only works if all of the components are identically sized. So I would have to concatenate some zeros to the L0 component of each array. For my real example, this would waste a massive amount of memory.

So, is there anything like batched_mul! for GPU ComponentArrays? I highly doubt so and expect to have to write a CUDA kernel. But, cuBLAS matrix multiplication is incredibly optimized and complex. Will I have to write an entire CUDA kernel from the ground up including all of the basic matrix-matrix multiplication details? Or, is it possible that I could write a simple kernel that just iterates through the components (L0, L1, ...) and then calls cuBLAS to handle the matrix multiplication?

Also, note that I have to use ComponentArrays as this must all happen within an ODE solver. And, high performance is critical in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any actual scalar indexing happening here.

I have no immediate access to a GPU machine right now, but what happens if you change that loop to

```
for k in names
    getproperty(c, k) .= getproperty(a, k) * getproperty(b, k)
end
```

I would hope this might get rid of the scalar indexing warning.

For the small arrays in your example the kernel launch overhead is very likely dominating, which is why the computation is slow. I assume your real workload is much larger?

Since the computations in each iteration of your loop are independent of each other, you could schedule them asynchronously as explained here: https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/usage/multitasking/